# What is the meaning of "もとになった"?

Tags: expressions

What is the meaning of "もとになった"?

Here is the sentence in which I find this expression:

> **もとになった**鳥山先生のイラストはDB大全集第６番182ページ掲載.

Maybe simply, (this illustration) *originally* was published on [...]?

For more context:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/f8bLhA1.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means:

the *original* illustration was published in ...

The version here is an altered/modified version based on the original illuatration.

[Weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%82%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B) translates もとになる as "become the basis". Here "もとになった" is used to modify "鳥山先生のイラスト". So it literally means:
The illustration of Mr. Toriyama that became/is the basis (of this illustration) ...

Answer (score 2):

If X is the もと of Y, it means X is the original that Y was based on. So in this case, the もとになった…イラスト would be the illustration that the pictured cel was based on. (Presumably the pictured illustration is from a cel created by Toei, and the もとになったイラスト would be the illustration by Toriyama that's mentioned in the passage above.)